# How can I make og: meta tags work properly in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, next.js, facebook-opengraph

I would like to add [OpenGraph](https://ogp.me/) meta tags to a page of my NextJS app. I added meta the tags inside the `<Head>` component exposed through [`next/head`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head).

However, when I tested the OpenGraph data through the [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and [opengraph.xyz](https://opengraph.xyz), both tools said no og properties were properly set.

To investigate, I opened up developer tools on the page and under the 'Elements' tab, all the og meta tags I had set were present under the `<head>` element. However, when I hit 'View page source' or made a request to the page through Postman, the og `<meta>` tags were not there.

This makes me think that the elements inside the `<Head>` element are added by NextJS through javascript once the page is loaded. This would explain why Facebook's crawler does not see the tags, as the crawler likely does not load javascript when crawling links.

Is there a way to have the meta tags work properly when using NextJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the package `next-firebase-auth`, and when I changed

```
export default withAuthUser({
    whenAuthed: AuthAction.REDIRECT_TO_APP,
    whenUnauthedBeforeInit: AuthAction.SHOW_LOADER,
    whenUnauthedAfterInit: AuthAction.RENDER,

})(MyPage)
```

to

```
export default MyPage
```

the meta tag showed up properly.

I will post an update if I find a way to make the `<Head>` element work properly with the `next-firebase-auth` package.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to help you with a link or snippet of the code.  Maybe it's an issue with duplicate tags, and you can solve this with a `key` property.

```
{/* Example */}

<Head>
...

{/* Twitter */}
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" key="twcard" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content={twitterHandle} key="twhandle" />

{/* Open Graph */}
<meta property="og:url" content={currentURL} key="ogurl" />
<meta property="og:image" content={previewImage} key="ogimage" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content={siteName} key="ogsitename" />
<meta property="og:title" content={pageTitle} key="ogtitle" />
<meta property="og:description" content={description} key="ogdesc" />

...
</Head>
```

**edit:** There's an issue with fast refresh while using `withAuthUser()` and is reported as a bug in `next-firebase-auth` roadmap. Maybe its related with your question:
https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth/issues/265